# startup items folder

Tags: startup

MAC PRO 1,1

it says: Insecure Startup items folder detected .... Items in startupitems folder have not been started because the folder does not have the proper security settings

my question:I checked in About this mac, then more info, then under software Startup items - and there I read: No information found.

I think I deleted what is supposed to be there by mistake. Please let me know what it is to be

there and if I can get that to put it there please help.

Comment: Which version of macOS are you using and what is in your `~/Library/LaunchAgents` directory.  Please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/347166/edit) your post with updates to the question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am still using 10.6. from 2007. Not a tech person. Please let me know where are these - how to find them ...

Comment: I found it . It says

Comment: at.obdev.LittleSnitchNetworkMonitor.plist
at.obdev.LittleSnitchUIAgent.plist

Comment: And in Startupitems the folder is empty ...

Answer (score 1):

StartupItems apply to all users, therefore the folder needs to be owned by root. You can set this by running the following, then rebooting.

```
sudo chown -R root:wheel /Library/StartupItems/
```